# UTL_FILE for dummies (me)

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Bit of a newbie with SQL developer, trying to figure out both Packages, and UTL_File package at the same time.

I've created a package, and am trying to write a procedure that creates a file, but I'm a bit unsure on when/where to declare my variables. Following procedure is in my Package body, but doesn't work.

```
PROCEDURE NewFile IS

DECLARE
  v_file  utl_file.file_type;
  v_filename  VARCHAR2(20) := 'TIMtest.dat';
BEGIN
  v_file := utl_file.fopen ('TIM_DIR', v_filename, 'A');
  utl_file.put_line(v_file, 'Hello World @ ' || to_char(sysdate));
  utl_file.fclose(v_file);

END NewFile;
```

The error I get is:

Error(13,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type      current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

Evidently the problem is with where/how I'm declaring my variables, but I'm not sure where they go, if not there.

Comment: Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373). DECLARE is not valid here.

Comment: Good lord, I am useless. Thank you very much.